# CodeIgniter: Display Pop up message

Tags: php, codeigniter

My scenario is:
When user clicks on Add to cart icon, a product has to store in database by displaying a message, '**Product Added to Cart**.'

Here I have used json url :

```
$add_to_cat = http://www.sitename.com/cgi-bin/phts.sh/js/jsread.p?call=basket&user=&lang=en&id=".$user_logged_id."&type=in&ph=".$product_id;
```

which is used to store the record in Progress Database Server.

My code is :

```
if(redirect($add_to_cat, 'location')){
 // here I want pop up message          
}
```

When redirection occurs, json file is displayed which I dont want. I just want to display a message with out opening json record file.

Answer (score 1):

Use [flash data](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) (part of the session class).

In the controller do something like;

```
if(redirect($add_to_cat, 'location')){
   $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Added to cart');          
}
```

Then in your view, something like;

```
<?php
    if ($this->session->flashdata('message')) {
    ?>
    <div class="message flash">
        <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('message'); ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
?>
```